# R Calculate most important value for each row in data frame by rules

Tags: r, dataframe, scoring

I have a question where I have some issues solving it.
I have a data frame in which I have collected in each row 4 labels and corresponding score values. Here´s my sample data:

```
sample = data.frame("label1" = c("name1", "name1", "name3"), "score1" = c(0.88, 0.5, 0.4),
                    "label2" = c("name1", "name1", "name3"), "score2" = c(0.93, 0.6, 0.35),
                    "label3" = c("name2", "name1", "name4"), "score3" = c(0.49, 0.7, 0.8),
                    "label4" = c("name2", "name2", "name1"), "score4" = c(0.81, 0.8, 0.25), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Now I would like to calculate for each row a final label and score by the following rules:

- if a label appears more than 2 times then this is the final label and the corresponding value is the mean of the score values of this label
- if there are two different labels in one row which both appear two times, then the label with the higher mean of score values should be choosen with the corresponding mean of score values
- if there are more than two different labels in a row, it is not clear which one to choose. So there should be an NA and the corresponding value is also NA.

I thought of looping through the data frame by row and restructuring the row to use `aggregate`. Here´s my approach for the first row:

```
pairs <- as.data.frame(matrix(as.vector(sample[1,]), ncol=2, byrow = TRUE))
pairs = data.frame("label" = unlist(pairs[,1], recursive = FALSE), "score" = unlist(pairs[,2], recursive = FALSE))
pairs$label = as.character(pairs$label)

aggregate(score~label, data=pairs, FUN = function(x) c(mean = mean(x), count = length(x) ))
```

After this point, I have no idea how to implement the above rules. Any maybe there is a more efficient way to solve this?
This is my desired output:

```
result = data.frame("label" = c("name1", "name1", NA), "score" = c(0.905, 0.6, NA))
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: If anyone want to pickup from here and write rules for each of the sublist, here it is. I can't summarize(?) the sublist/results without writing low quality/really verbose code. Here it is with some matrix() abuse. `lapply(1:nrow(sample), function(n) sample[n,,drop=F]) %>%
    lapply(matrix, ncol = 2, byrow = T) %>%
    lapply(as.data.frame)`

Comment: Well how would you do that (even some long code would be fine for the first step)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like you, I too think restructuring the data and aggregating it is the way to go, and that's what I did here:

```
library(dplyr)
sample$row_num <- 1:nrow(sample)

new_lst <- lapply(1:4, 
              function(x){
                    cols <- names(sample)[grepl(x, names(sample))]
                    sample[, c(cols, "row_num")] %>% 
                      setNames(c( "label", "score", "row_num"))
                  })


sample_2 <- do.call(rbind, new_lst) %>% 
      group_by(row_num, label) %>% 
      summarise(cnt = n(),
                score_avg = mean(score))
```

and now I go through each row and apply the rules which I use if-elseif-else to code

```
lapply(1:nrow(sample), 
       function(x){
         dat <- sample_2 %>% filter(row_num == x) 

         if(max(dat$cnt) > 2) {

           label <- as.character(dat[which((dat$cnt) > 2), "label"])
           score <- dat[dat$label == label, "score_avg"]

         } else if (nrow(dat) > 2) {

           label <- NA
           score <- NA

         } else {

           label <- as.character(dat[which.max(dat$score_avg), "label"])
           score <- max(dat$score_avg)

         }
         return(data.frame(# "row_num" = x,  # you can un-comment here to have an indexed output
                           "label" = label, "score" = score))
         }) %>% 
    data.table::rbindlist()
```

not very elegant but it does the job

hope this helps